# Algorithm to test dependency preservation

Tags: database-theory, relational-algebra

Is there an algorithm to test whether the decomposition of relation $R$ into relations $R_1,\dots,R_n$ is dependency-preserving?

In more detail, I am given a relation $R(x_1,\dots,x_m)$ on $m$ variables.  I am given a decomposition of $R$ into relations $R_1,\dots,R_n$, where each relation $R_i$ refers to a subset of the variables $\{x_1,\dots,x_m\}$.  I am also given a set of functional dependencies $F$ for $R$.  I would like to know whether this decomposition is dependency-preserving.  Is there an efficient algorithm to answer this question?

Recall the definition of "dependency-preserving" from database theory: the decomposition of $R$ into $R_1,\dots,R_n$ is dependency-preserving if $F^+=G^+$, where $G=G_1 \cup \dots \cup G_n$ and $G_i$ is the restriction of $F$ to the variables of $R_i$ (so $G_i$ is a set of functional dependencies for $R_i$).

Comment: This is an attempt to write a general reference question that can be useful to other users in the future (something that generalizes beyond any one exercise problem).

Comment: should I delete my question now?

Comment: @amalsom, nope, don't delete your question.  It can still be useful to others to help them find a good resource.  Thank you for asking!

Comment: :Question is quite interesting. The algos I can find are not clear. In `Navathe's` book there is no such reference to this also. Thx.